# Extending existing offline access_tokens

Tags: facebook, access-token

i have to extend the offline access token of all users stored in my database

here i found the method
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

but when i used this call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

for some users i get the new token

```
access_token=xxxxxxx&expires=5102358
```

for others i don't receive anything why?

i use this code

```
$request_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=xxxx&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=xxxx";
```

$info = file_get_contents($request_url);

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access token for the other users might have already expired by the time you're trying to convert it.  You can ONLY extend non-expired access tokens.  Once they expire, you will need to have you user come back to the app to reauth.

Comment: I was under the impression that facebooks implementation of the OAuth did not include the refresh token part. Was that changed? Is there any official documentation for that? I can't find any

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/ See the *Client-side OAuth and Extending Access_Token Expiration Time through New Endpoint* section.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&  this code gives me acesstoken in FF Chrome but not in IE all versions it shows the result as 
    {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"Error: Access is denied.\r\n"}